# MongoDB or MySQL for a complex browser game on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, heroku

I am implementing a browser based game with a small group of friends using RoR, meant to be deployed on Heroku. We were implementing everything regarded to databases on MySQL. However, Heroku's free/cheap MySQL databases are shared and inefficient, and there is no intermediate level; the dedicated ones are pretty expensive for our start. Therefore, we started considering the MongoDB solutions that are provided, which are much more accessible, when considering prices.

However, our application will have lots of tables, with lots of relations and foreigns keys. For instance, we will have tables for attacks, for units present in those attacks, for every tile in the map and what is inside it, and among others.

Therefore, would there be any performance issue or problem on using MongoDB? I know that, although it can create relationships between its collections, it is not mean 100% for that, right? Should we stick with a bad and shared MySQL database until we can afford a dedicated one, or there is no need for them, and we can stick with MongoDB with no big issues?

Consider that we will have a lot of queries and updates, and all of them will probably reference relationships between different tables/collections.

Comment: If your database needs include referential integrity, I believe there is no choice -- MySQL.

Comment: I thought Heroku favored PostgreSQL?

Comment: We were operating with a MySQL instance on Amazon RDS, which is simple to setup on Heroku. But, indeed, Heroku favors PostreSQL; I made it sound like the opposite, my bad. However, this is not the issue, they are still relational...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work with both mySQL and mongoDB for different applications.

When we're working with an object oriented structure we generally go mongoDB over mySQL due to the nature of it's design of mongoDB being object oriented.

When we're requiring more relational data (like user profiles, friendships and messages as an example) we go with mySQL as it is definitely better for relational data.

My team finds that the first week or so with mongoDB is a bit tough (as most are so used to mySQL) but after that they generally prefer it to work with, for example no predefined schema's are required, just get started with the collection. The order of data in mongoDB must be respected ALOT more than in mySQL also. So you're aware, we're using a jQuery AJAX with JSON structure over PHP with mongoDB for the current application we're working on.

Maintenance and admin wise, much of a muchness, but mongoDB does struggle more if SOMEONE (I'm not naming names Pablo), forgets to index something. 
We did have a monogDB server crash a couple of weeks due to this. I restarted the server and again crashed, so I had to re-route all traffic to another temporary server that was about to go online as a back-up server for mongoDB, because of this everything was in place for the new server to take the place of the existing server temporarily luckily. When I started the server with no queries, found the problem, added the index and as soon as I added it and put it back online the processors went from insanely high to normal, no problems since.

Personally I tend to try to be a little more proactive with mongoDB because the issues that come up can be more severe than mySQL, in what happened with our crash, mySQL probably would have experience slowness but mongoDB in the same situation did crash completely.

I like them both though and will use them both moving to the future but the right choice and doing the basics is really important, more so for mongoDB in my opinion.

I hope this extra insight helps a little.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is said on several places that MongoDB is more efficient than MySQL in some aspects. Do you think that this 'better performance' can compensate the loss of performance of performing lots of join-like operations on MongoDB (by breaking queries)? This seem hard to be answered, but.. haha. Regarding the MongoDB embedded objects, each one of them will be a copy of the original? Are there any syncing issues? Can different entrances in a MongoDB collection have different sizes, depending on what they embed? lots of questions.. ps.: the index comment was hilarious hahahaha

Comment: No worries. 1. based on the information provided (plus a randomly thrown dart at big 'yes' & 'no' signs), I THINK so; 2. basically yes; 3. getting used to the differences is the biggest issue; 4. depending on what they embed, yes. Max 2GB per collection; Glad you liked it, bloody Pablo! For you to get a good feel for mongo, if you have time, try to build a basic application with mongo first, for example a simple "CMS", just page content, META info & anything else unique in the collection to get a feel for how it works. Use the scripting language & methods you plan to use in your application :)

Comment: I'm going to give it a try later, thanks! And, oh, now that I saw it, you are brazilian too! hahaha I am from Curitiba

Comment: No problem at all Fernando, just don't rush the set-up of the database, I did that on my laptop as a testing environment when I first tested mongo & had a couple of small teething issues, once I reinstalled it taking my time it was great. Hehe, or should I say rsrs? I actually had a feeling you were from Brazil based on a combination of the way you communicate and your name. I'm actually a Kiwi (from New Zealand) but I live in Floripa now as you probably noticed. Small world. I like Curitiba but don't get to go up often, only if I'm going to São Paulo by car. Boa tarde amigo.

Comment: Your answer is fine, but I cannot say I have ever heard of anyone who had `mongod` "crash" because of missing indexes.  Either way, missing indexes will hurt the performance of any database, including MySQL.

Comment: @Bryan We have seen it a couple of times before, not common but it does happen. We have seen a couple of other developers asking about it in various forums around so we're comfortable that it's not an error on our part

Comment: If I have a collection with lots of other embedded collections and, possibly, more embedded collections inside those already embedded collections, where should the index be placed? On the ''top'' collection (like index "map.tile.column")? Or should I put the indexes individually on each collection? Thanks again! Fernando.

Comment: @Fernando We only have 1 embedded collection ourselves and from memory we placed an index in it. Because we don't need to embed our collections I couldn't tell you what the best practice is off the top of my head sorry mate.

Answer (score 3):

Rather impossible to answer.  Only you and your team know your data model and know if it can fit into a nested, hierarchical, document.

Just because you have alot of foreign key constraints, tables, JOINs, etc does not mean that you cannot change the entire data model to work with MongoDB (or any other NoSQL for that matter), but you'll probably need to do quite a bit of work to change your data model and access patterns.

Unfortunately, like I said above, we don't know if that is possible with your current application design.

Check out http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design and http://www.slideshare.net/kbanker/mongodb-schema-design

Comment: My colleagues liked the idea of adopting MongoDB, but it worries me. We will have to perform a lot of join-like operations, which would result in a simple MySQL-like query to be broken on some consecutive MongoDB queries. I am no expert on MongoDB, but that embedding operation will basically create a copy of the embedded object on the main table, right? Therefore, what if I change the embedded object on its own collection? Will that affect performance too? I am a little lost, because I know much about SQL-like databases, and not much about MongoDB, been reading about it for less than a day..

Comment: Valid concerns, and great questions.  If you embed data inside of documents, you risk the possibility of having to embed the same data in many documents - leading to storage, queryability, update and out-of-sync concerns.  This can sometimes be mitigated by modeling your data differently. Its tough to break free of SQL-style modeling and think in JSON but it gets easier.  If you embed, you won't have to do JOIN's.  Also, while its much less efficient, it isn't terrible to have separate collections in Mongo and join them in the application layer.   Either way, choose the right tool for the job!

Answer (score 1):

An application that depends on a lot of highly relational data probably shouldn't be implemented with a non-relational database.

Comment: Being designed to depend on *the feature set* of a relational database is much different than being dependent on the relational database.  In most cases, data can be modeled differently to depend on anything.  Surely there are cases where that statement is untrue, but uninformed answers are not meaningful answers.

Comment: In a relational database I would already have lots of join operations.. In MongoDB I won't be able to "embed" everything, as this seem to consume lots of resources. Therefore, I would have to do many queries to "hunt" the data I need step-by-step, I am not sure if this is OK. The worst operations are related to the map table, as it is very dynamic, and also about the 'attack' table, because a single attack will reference two users (attacker and defender), and there will be another table with lots of entries, where each row references an attack entry and corresponds to an unit quantity and kind